# multiple control arrays within one form

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have an array called `lblTables` which contains 21 lables of my form. This works perfectly fine. The code for it is below:

```
Public lblTables() As Label
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    lblTables = New Label() {Label2, table1, table2, table3, table4, table5, table6, table7, table8, table9, table10,
    table11, table12, table13, table14, table15, table16, table17, table18, table19, table20}
End Sub
```

I need to create another array called `lblStartTimes` which will contain another 21 labels. So i proceeded as follows:

```
Private lblStartTimes() As Label
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    lblStartTimes = New Label() {startTime1, startTime2, startTime3, startTime4, startTime5, startTime6,
    startTime7, startTime8, startTime9, startTime10, startTime11, startTime12, startTime13, startTime14,
    startTime15, startTime16, startTime17, startTime18, startTime19, startTime20}
End Sub
```

But when i tried to do that i got an error saying `Public Sub New() has multiple definitions with identical signatures`. So after doing a research i found the easiest way of doing this would be as follows:

```
Public lblStartTimes() As Label = {Label3, startTime1, startTime2, startTime3, startTime4, startTime5, startTime6,
    startTime7, startTime8, startTime9, startTime10, startTime11, startTime12, startTime13, startTime14,
    startTime15, startTime16, startTime17, startTime18, startTime19, startTime20}
```

but when i use this method i'm constantly receiving a `System.NullReferenceException` error. i need to declare `lblStartTimes` the same OR similar way i declared `lblTables` array without getting the **multiple definitions** error. How can i achieve this?

Comment: `Sub New` is called the constructor - it is what creates the form.  It only needs one.  It wont know how to use two.  Just add the  `blStartTimes = New Label() {...}` code to the first ctor and delete the one you added.  Please read [Ask] and take the [tour]. (Also those arrays need not be `Public`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like already suggested in the comments, you *are allowed* to write multiple lines in the constructor. Just move the second array initialization code to the first constructor:

```
Public lblTables() As Label
Public lblStartTimes() As Label

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    lblTables = New Label() {Label2, table1, table2, table3, table4, table5, table6, table7, table8, table9, table10,
table11, table12, table13, table14, table15, table16, table17, table18, table19, table20}
    lblStartTimes = New Label() {startTime1, startTime2, startTime3, startTime4, startTime5, startTime6,
startTime7, startTime8, startTime9, startTime10, startTime11, startTime12, startTime13, startTime14,
startTime15, startTime16, startTime17, startTime18, startTime19, startTime20}
End Sub
```